# What version of Pyramid do I have and what's the best way to update?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid and I'm wondering how I can check what version I'm currently using. Also, how can I update my Pyramid?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To know which version of pyramid you have, you can run this in a python console :

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("pyramid").version
```

To update, you could run `pip install --upgrade pyramid`, but in order to update pyramid and all its dependencies, I advice you to replace your current virtualenv and replace it with a new one, with a fresh install of pyramid. The [installation procedure](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/install.html#creating-the-virtual-python-environment) in the documentation should help you if you are not sure about how to do that.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, basically, updating is not possible...you just have to start over and re-install.

Comment: Well, more or less. `pip` can upgrade one package, but last time I checked, there was no easy way to upgrade all the packages. Reinstalling is cheap, and that way you are sure you have a clean virtualenv.

Comment: damn... yeah running into an issue where I upgraded Python and now mako doesn't work and I can't fix it. Looks like this is the only solution :/

Comment: still valid for Windows 10 and PowerShell!