# ValueError: No such renderer factory .mak - Python Pyramid error

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons, mako

I upgraded to Python 1.4.5 and when I try to run my project here is the error:

```
ValueError: No such renderer factory .mak
[Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WhoAt/env/www/www/views/index/index.py line:32]
get()
     ->return self.render(mak)

[Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WhoAt/env/www/www/views/__init__.py line:231]
render()
     ->response = render_to_response(template, context, request=self.request)

[Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WhoAt/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/renderers.py line:138]
render_to_response()
     ->return helper.render_to_response(value, None, request=request)

ValueError: No such renderer factory .mak
```

I looked this up yesterday and learned that mako templates aren't supported by default anymore. And they have to be added back in: [What's New In Pyramid 1.5](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/whatsnew-1.5.html)

I followed the steps on that docs page, but am still getting the error :(

In the **init**.py

```
config.include('pyramid_mako') # < added that
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
config.scan()
return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

And in the setup.py added 'pyramid_mako' and chameleon

```
requires = [
    'pyramid',
    'pyramid_mako',
    'pyramid_chameleon',
    'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
    'waitress',
]
```

Also ran the setup.py in terminal :(

Has anyone else run into problems fixing mako templates in PyCharm?

A print list of my pip freeze: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/Bvakw/

Comment: Looks like I may have found my answer here :( re-creating my virtualenv now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888577/what-version-of-pyramid-do-i-have-and-whats-the-best-way-to-update/10895485#10895485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to recreate my VirtualEnv and start fresh. Was able to fix the missing mak problem

Answer here [What version of Pyramid do I have and what's the best way to update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888577/what-version-of-pyramid-do-i-have-and-whats-the-best-way-to-update/10895485#10895485) by [@madjar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981855/madjar)

Answer (score 0):

Since i was also suffering from the same problem (`No such renderer factory .mak`) i was wondering for the solution.
Then i got a link of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid/1.5a2 and it helped me to get out of this problem.
This error means that the application is searching for a template either it is mako or chameleon but since it fails to find out the **Renderer** our application throws this error.

The main reason of this error is that, In pyramid 1.5a2+, the Pyramid community is moving mako tepmlate in a package named `pyramid_mako` and the chameleon template is being moved to a package named `pyramid_chameleon`.

So to solve this problem i made some changes in my `setup.py` and `__init.py__`.

**Case1.** If  your templating system is chameleon
in `setup.py` add following lines in

`setup(..........)`

`install_requires=[
        'pyramid_chameleon',
        'pyramid',
    ],`
And in `__init__.py` add following lines

`config.include('pyramid_chameleon')`

**Case2** If your templating system is mako
in `setup.py` add following lines in

`setup(..........)`

`install_requires=[
        'pyramid_mako',
        'pyramid',
    ],`
And in `__init__.py` add following lines

`config.include('pyramid_mako')`

Then try to run the `setup.py` and then run the `develpoment.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I set up project using starter scaffolding which takes by default chameleon. So after changing it to jinja2 in setup.py and **init.py** had an similar error but in my case it was .pt

So what was happening is it's still calling the default templating engine in  views.py it had previously so changed it on views.py. Add the respective template file in the template directory with respective file.For example I removed the .pt format file and added the .jinja2 template files.

Don't forget to use the respective format for the template you are using.
Worked well than